# Get the biggest key from Object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object `{"1": "a", "2": "b", "3": "c"}`
How could I get **max key**?
I don't need a value, just key, so I would like to have 3 of type number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all key values and from them get the largest using [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) method with [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method.

```js
var obj = {
  "1": "a",
  "2": "b",
  "3": "c"
};

console.log(
  Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(obj))
)

// or with ES6 spread syntax
console.log(
  Math.max(...Object.keys(obj))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using [**`reduce()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the keys:

```js
var data = {"1": "a", "2": "b", "3": "c"};
var max = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(a, b) { 
    return a > +b ? a : +b;
});

console.log(max);
```

Comment: Wrong condition. Must be a>+b ? a:+b

Comment: @Jonasw Thanks for the improvement. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {"1": "a", "2": "b", "3": "c"}
var max = 0;

for (var property in data) {
  max = (max < parseFloat(property)) ? parseFloat(property) : max;
}

console.log(max);
```